# htaccess 301 redirect GET-Parameter and remove it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am in a need of a 301-Redirect with the following example:

**The pages**

- https://www.example.com/index.php?id=
- https://www.example.com/?id=

**Should be redirected to**

- https://www.example.com

but i really do not understand how to solve that.

What i have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{query_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule https://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `?` at the end of target URI to strip off any existing query string. Also you can use a relative target URI also if target is on same domain.

Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php)?$ /? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Only for the index page: `RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php)?$ /? [NC,R=301,L]`

Comment: @xcy7e: Warm namaste to you as well, glad it worked out.

Comment: will this occur in redirecting this too? e. g. http://example.com/index.php?id=1337

Comment: How to avoid that? [index.php?id= -- redirect] [index.php?id=123 -- no redirect]

Comment: Change condition to: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(?!123\b) [NC]`

Comment: Thanks. (How) can i solve that dynamically? Means any ID mustn't be redirected.

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=$`

Comment: You are such a pro. Big help. So glad you helped me out. Stay well, be blessed